# Load table with titles from JSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire

I have a page with a TableView that fills each cell with a hardcoded UILabel of some text. I would like it to fill up with UILabels from a JSON that I get online.

Storyboard:
[image]

The code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var objects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()

self.objects.add("iPhone")
self.objects.add("Apple Watch")
self.objects.add("Mac")
self.objects.add("Test")
self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
return self.objects.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

cell.titleLabel.text = self.objects.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as? String
//cell.logButton.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row;
//cell.logButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.logAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath){
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showView", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func logAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
let titleString = self.objects[sender.tag] as? String
let firstActivityItem = "\(titleString!)"
let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
if (segue.identifier == "showView"){
            let upcoming: NewViewController = segue.destination as! NewViewController

            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            let titleString = self.objects.object(at: indexPath.row) as? String

            upcoming.titleString = titleString

            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }

    }

}
```

Once in simulator and I open up the page, the TableView will have four cells with the "Label" changing to whatever was adding to the `objects` array, which in this case is iPhone, Apple Watch, Mac, and Test. Rather than having those hardcoded, I would like to have the items loaded from a JSON file.

I have the same thing done with a PickerView, but I am struggling to figure out how to do it with this. Here is how it was done with my PickerView if it helps:

Alamofire.request("example.com/file.json").responseJSON{ response in

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject] {


self.mypickerview.delegate = self
self.mypickerview.dataSource = self
let result = JSON.values.flatMap({ String(describing: $0) })
self.pickerData.append(contentsOf: result)
self.pickerData.sort()
self.verbose.text = "Content saved!"
self.mypickerview.reloadAllComponents()
self.mypickerview.delegate = self;
self.verbose.text = "Finished Loading!"

}
}
```

The JSON file:

```
{"One":"Mac","Two":"Apple iPhone","Three":"Test"}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is basically the same thing as what is done in the PickerView.

Comment: @Caleb That same code does not work with an NSMutableArray like it does with this: `var pickerData: [String] = [String]()` so I simply tried converting an NSMutableArray to a normal array with some code but that didn't work. It showed a blank TableView

Answer (score 0):

1.On viewDidLoad fire the webService.
2.On Webservice completion handler ,retreive the label values and assign to objects.
3.Reload tableview.

Answer (score 0):

your JSON should look like this:

{
  "titles": [
    "mac",
    "iphone",
    "test"
  ]
}

and you will do something like `cell.titleLabel.text = [[yourJSON valueForKey:@"titles"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

(this is Obj-C version, but ofc it can be done also in swift)